# How does the sDNA calculate betweenness?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sdna

I want to calculate the betweenness value by my hand, and then compare with sDNA calculated. But I found that I can't get the value same as what sdna calculated.

Here's my case:
[image: link_A]

Assume all the links length of this network is 500 meters. While calcualte the betweenness value for the link A with raidus 600 meters, totally 7 links should be considered(please refer the bold links in the picture).

I calcuate the betweenness as the following:

**betweeness value of A = 1/2*6+9+1/3 = 12.3333**

But **the sDNA calculate the betweeness 6.3333.**   Please refer the following sDNA picture. 
[image: betweenness_sdna]
How does the sDNA get that result and why?

My test environment:
- ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2
- sDNA 3.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discrete space (i.e. if you haven't selected continuous space), links are included in a radius if their *midpoint* falls within the radius. For betweenness, this means the radius from the geodesic's *origin* link, not necessarily the same as the link where betweenness is being measured.

Also, don't forget that in the absence of one way links, geodesics count in both directions.

Thus betweenness (600m) for link A is

```
A-A Self betweenness contribution 1/3
Geodesic Endpoint contributions: 1/2 for each of
    1-A, 2-A, 3-A, 4-A, 5-A, 6-A
    A-1, A-2, A-3, A-4, A-5, A-6

1/3 + 12 * 0.5 = 6.3333
```

The following geodesics measure 1000m from midpoint to midpoint so are not included in 600m betweenness:

```
1-4 1-5 1-6 2-4 2-5 2-6 3-4 3-5 3-6
4-1 5-1 6-1 4-2 5-2 6-2 4-3 5-3 6-3
```

Presumably this is the source of the confusion and the **9** in your sum.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answering! I can understand it now!